# Party at the Johnsons's?

Tags: apostrophe, names

What is the proper use of the apostrophe in this phrase:

> The party is at the Johnsons's

Assuming, the regular form of the last name is "Johnson" and there are at least two people in the Johnson family.

I assume it should be possessive because it is implied that it is referring to their house.

What would the correct form be for a last name ending in an S in its singular form?

Comment: The main point of confusion for me was handling the "implicit house" in addition to the (better documented) rules dealing with plural surnames.

Comment: The implicit house is irrelevant. Since you're dealing with the genetive the rule is exactly the same.

Comment: @MattЭллен No, the implicit house is critical. If you don't realise that there's an implicit house, then it a simple plural requiring no apostrophe at all.

Comment: @TrevorD ok, I'll rephrase — that it's a house is irellevant. Of course there's is an implicit object, in fact the OP states that this is their assumption.

Comment: @MattЭллен Sorry, my comment was because when I first read the question I didn't appreciate that there was an implicit anything (hence the second part of my comment), and I overlooked the OP's comment. Will delete both comments shortly.

Comment: Stupid to close an obviously different question for 'already answered' just because the answers overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At the Johnsons'

would be my suggestion. There is an implicit "house" at the end

I have also seen

> At the Joneses'

for a house belonging to the Jones family

Have a look at these many pages https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=possessive+s+ending+on+s

Answer (score 0):

When we are talking about the family we normally say: *The* Browns even if the surname, Brown, is singular. When expressing possession the apostrophe comes after the plural form, e.g.

> The Browns' dog.

This does not change even if the surname, singular, ends with an "s".

> The Thomas' dog

The dog belongs to the whole family.

The same rule applies when talking about the family home.

> At the Browns'
>
> At the Thomas'

(Although I would *say*: At the Thomases (*/ˈtɒməsɪz/*)

If however we are talking about only a single member of the family then the apostrophe goes immediately between the name and the genitive "s".

> Mr Brown's job

and

> Mr Thomas's job

Comment: I would prefer _the Thomases' dog_ to _the Thomas'._

Comment: I agree that it sounds better in speech but in the written form it *might* lead someone to think the surname is Thomases, although I don't think such a surname exists.

Comment: If the surname were _Thomases,_ then the plural possessive would be _Thomaseses',_ akin to _Joneses'._ Of course, that would be awful.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Very awful, agreed! However, I believe in its written form, *The Thomas' dog*, the apostrophe after the "s" is clearly understood by the vast majority. All to his own personal preference and style, I guess.

Comment: Agreed, I wouldn't say that _Thomas'_ is incorrect – although a possessive plural **should** normally end in a voiced S sound, which you don't have unless you form the plural as _Thomases_ first.